# what do i need to modify in the code to make my desired output?

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns, while-loop

```
A B C D E D C B A 
A B C D   D C B A   
A B C       C B A     
A B           B A       
A               A
```

make this pattern using the code below:

```
n = int(input('\nEnter the No. of rows : '))
n=n//2+1

print('\n')
# this is a never ending loop
r=n
i=-1
s=chr(64+1)

while r>=n:
 c=j=1
 while c<=n*2-1:
  print(s if c<=r else ' ',end='')
  if c==n: j=-1
  c=c+j
 print()
 if r==1: i=1
 r=r+i
 if i==1 and r>n:
   break
```

previously i also made and succeded in making hollow diamond inscribed in rectangle so here it is:

```
n = int(input('\nEnter the No. of rows : '))
n=n//2+1
print('\n')

r=n
i=-1
while r<=n:
 c=j=1
 while c>=1:
  print('*' if c<=r else ' ',end='')
  if c==n: j=-1
  c=c+j
 print()
 if r==1: i=1
 r=r+i

print()
```

i have tried many ways but the code isnt working. i only want in this format so please understand and edit the code

i was expecting this:

```
A B C D E D C B A 
A B C D   D C B A   
A B C       C B A     
A B           B A       
A               A
```

but i am unable to make this.

Comment: _but i am unable to make this_ Why not?  What is stopping you?  You ought to be able to step through the code line by line and know exactly what it is doing.  Can you do that?

Comment: Please use the PEP-8 recommended 4 spaces of indentation to make the block structure easier to read.

Comment: Your code prints `*` instead of letters. It seems like you must have just copied the answer to a similar question, and made no attempt to convert it to your desired output.

Comment: Your code prints a second set of triangles pointing the other direction. Again, that suggests that you didn't write this code at all, it was copied from the solution to a different problem. You're not going to learn to program by just copying and pasting.

Comment: the thing is stopping me is the mindset required to program. everyone who starts programming for the first time have to build a certain way of thinking how to make a program.

Comment: no matter if it prints '*' or alphabets i provided the code as a sample working code which help people understand what exactly i need. Thank you for your comment Barmar I know that copy pasting is wrong and the different problem have same procedure. i needed to try something new otherwise today i made this program with same boring way which everyone uses.

Comment: I am sorry for not following PEP-8. Its my first time here and just got to know PEP-8 after reading your comment. I use notepad to code as i was told countless time if its your first ever programming language dont make an habit of using an IDE as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's better to separate the print the first line and the rest lines. Here is the code to print what you want.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as ASCII


def print_pyramid_1(size: int, cnt: int):
    print_str = ''
    for idx in range(cnt):
        print_str += ASCII[idx]
        print_str += ' '

    # print space
    for _ in range((size - cnt) * 2 - 1):
        print_str += '  '

    for idx in range(cnt - 2, -1, -1):
        print_str += ASCII[idx]
        print_str += ' '

    print(f'{print_str}\n')


def print_pyramid_2(size: int, cnt: int):
    print_str = ''
    for idx in range(cnt):
        print_str += ASCII[idx]
        print_str += ' '

    # print space
    for _ in range((size - cnt) * 2 - 1):
        print_str += '  '

    for idx in range(cnt - 1, -1, -1):
        print_str += ASCII[idx]
        print_str += ' '

    print(f'{print_str}\n')


def print_pyramid(number: int):
    total = number
    rows = total
    while rows >= 1:
        if total == rows:
            print_pyramid_1(total, rows)

        if total != rows:
            print_pyramid_2(total, rows)

        rows -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input('\nEnter the No. of rows : '))
    print_pyramid(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the `abs` function to calculate the distance to the character in the middle given a position:

```
n = 5
m = ord('A') + n - 1
for i in range(n):
    print(*( ' ' if (d := abs(n - 1 - j)) < i else chr(m - d) for j in range(2 * n - 1)))
```

This outputs:

```
A B C D E D C B A
A B C D   D C B A
A B C       C B A
A B           B A
A               A
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU0xDsIwENvzCm@5K2IAhIQqOvQphaQ0Fb1E1y68PhwwYMseLNkur23KcroUrVXQ4ewW86yBfO8ZOwj2OLgxKxKSQAd5RBJuHQxFk2zUELwxjaCAtsNwW@lbM83MuFo1PteI@6S0WBgYn8H5P3hE83ti5lrf)